# Installing brew on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew

I've encountered a problem while installing brew on my machine. The installation is a success till it creates a Homebrew directory in ~/local.

I've executed the following:
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

**Result**

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The Xcode Command Line Tools will be installed.

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin /usr/local/Homebrew
mkdir: /usr/local/bin: Not a directory
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin /usr/local/Homebrew
```

I've tried installing using superuser mode and the system does not allow to use the superuser mode to install files from internet source.

TIA

Comment: That sounds very messed up. Are you an admin User? If not, become one. Also  I recommend installing the Xcode command line tools yourself, first.  If that doesn’t help, make a _new_ admin User and do the installation there; it will definitely work and you can then migrate all your stuff into the new User.

Comment: That error message suggests that /usr/local/bin already exists, but isn't a directory. What does `ls -ld /usr/local/bin` print?

Comment: @GordonDavisson here's the result: -rwxr-xr-x  1 lionelcarneiro  staff  1976232 16 Jun 14:43 /usr/local/bin

Comment: @matt Tried working on the problem creating a new user. Ends up with the same error. In fact, if I try to access my /usr/local/bin through root directory without super user access, I'm not able to. Whereas, if I try to access /usr/local/ , I am able to access without root privileges. I'm still wondering why does bin require superuser to access it. That's the main cause where my installation fails as its not able to access bin folder.

Comment: @Lionel That's a plain file, rather than a directory like it should be. Try renaming it (`sudo mv /usr/local/bin /usr/local/not-really-bin`), then try the install again. Also, take a look a the file to see what it is (start with `file /usr/local/not-really-bin`).

Comment: Very weird. It’s like someone put a bin file where your bin directory should be. What I really don’t understand is how that could also be true in a new clean User.

Comment: I’ve found several similar cases. Here’s one: [Can't install Homebrew on Yosemite: /usr/local/lib already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293268/cant-install-homebrew-on-yosemite-usr-local-lib-already-exists) People do seem to mess up their /usr/local for some reason...

Comment: And a couple more cases: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/permission-issue-on-installing/6428

Comment: @matt `/usr/local/bin` is a system-wide location, not associated with any particular user account. If it's messed up for one user, it's messed up for all users.

Comment: @GordonDavisson You'd think that, but it's also true that when I couldn't install `brew` because of permissions problems, I made a new user and was able to install `brew` there. So there must be _some_ significant difference in them.

Comment: I solved the issue by changing the default permissions of the directory to rwx for all users and it worked. Cheers @GordonDavisson

Comment: @matt Thanks for your help. Much appreciated